# Загрузить, но не показывать страницу

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Каким образом можно загрузить, но не показывать страницу с помощью javascript? Т.е. что-то вроде аналога на PHP:

```
file_get_contents('http://google.ru')
```

В данном случае PHP запросит страницу google.ru, но браузеру отдавать не будет, ведь нету echo.

Comment: Скрытый iframe, не?

Comment: нет, см. мой ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам ответил: http://javascript.ru/php/file_get_contents